# Tomee JMX on AIX

Tags: jmx, putty, aix, apache-tomee

Using an IBM AIX 6.1 machine and IBM JDK, i tried to expose JMX ressource for an external use. When i try to connect to the remote UNIX machine from a windows machine using the host ip and the port used in exposure setup, VisualVM/JConsole informs me that i cannot do that. Is it a firewall problem on the UNIX side ? also i have tried tunneling the ports from the UNIX machine to the windows machine using OpenSSH and putty and still no results.

Can you help.

JMX Config :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=60003
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ibm2"
```

ibm2 is retrieved when running hostname command in AIX

Comment: "cannot do it" and "no results"?  You'll need to provide something more concrete.

Comment: Another way: Use Jolokia to expose JMX as rest APIs

Comment: Yes this is possible. You will need to post the results of what happens when you attempt to access JMX remotely. Copy and paste the commands or actions you are doing and the results.